# How to create <span> element from img alt tag and append it after <img> line

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, alt

I've some images with 'alt' tag and I want to extract 'alt' tag for every img and create a `<span> + alt tag + </span>` line after each img. I don't know how to do it with jQuery.

The result should be the following:

`<img alt="Madrid" class="gallery__block vertical" src="1.jpg">`
`<span>Madrid</span>`
`<img alt="Paris" class="gallery__block vertical" src="2.jpg">`
`<span>Paris</span>`
`<img alt="Rome" class="gallery__block vertical" src="3.jpg">`
`<span>Rome</span>`

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So select the image, loop over, read the attribute, and insert a new element.

```js
$("img").each(function(){
  var img = $(this);
  var span = $("<span/>");
  span.text(img.attr("alt"));
  img.after(span);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="Madrid" class="gallery__block vertical" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
<img alt="Paris" class="gallery__block vertical" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
<img alt="Rome" class="gallery__block vertical" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
```

Comment: It works perfectly! The best solution for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using this:

```
$("img.gallery__block").each(function() {
    var $image = $(this);
    var $altTag = $image.attr('alt');
    var $span = $("<span></span>");
    $span.append($altTag);
    $image.after($span);
});
```